# How to create a table for storing user input in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, input

I am trying to add a table to my Windows Form in Visual Studio for getting data from users of my application. The table should have 8 columns and the user should be able to input the number of rows they want. The user would then input values into the fields, just like with an Excel worksheet.

The values input by the user would then be used in further mathematical expressions.

I don't know how to do this as I am a complete beginner.

Comment: Do you just mean like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553233.aspx ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a DataGrid component to your form
and then initialize it with DataTable

DataTable is similar to an object[,] that can be used to display

EDIT:

After you add DataGrid to your form you'll need to initialize it like this:

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
for(int i=0;i<numOfColumns;i++)
{
    DataColumn column = new DataColumn("Column" + (i+1));
    tbl.Columns.Add(column);
}

dg.DataSource  = tbl;
```

Comment: Would I need to create a local database for this?

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to use column values as variables in further calculations?

Comment: You can access the DataTable very easily; As I mentioned, DataTable is just like an object[,] - Making it very simple to access each cell